# Appending the correct values from a list

Tags: python, selenium, instagram

I am making an Instagram bot and I store the names of the users that the bot has followed in file.txt.

```
    unique_photos = len(pic_hrefs)  # TODO Let this run once and check whether this block of code works or not
    followers_list = []  # Contains the names of the people you followed

    for pic_href in pic_hrefs:
        driver.get(pic_href)
        sleep(2)
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
        try:
            # Like this picture
            driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@aria-label='Like']").click()
            print("Picture liked")  # TODO After checking delete this line

            follow_button = driver.find_element_by_class_name('bY2yH')

            # Follow the user if not followed already
            if follow_button.text == "•\n" + "Follow":
                follow_button.click()
                followed = driver.find_element_by_class_name('e1e1d')
                followers_list.append(followed.text)
                with open("file.txt", 'a') as file:
                    file.write(",".join(followers_list))
                    file.write(",")

            else:
                continue

            for second in reversed(range(0, 3)):
                print_same_line("#" + tag + ': unique photos left: ' + str(unique_photos)
                                + " | Sleeping " + str(second))
                sleep(1)
        except Exception:
            sleep(2)
        unique_photos -= 1
```

This is the final result in the file.txt:

```
kr.dramas_,kr.dramas_,marcelly.lds,kr.dramas_,marcelly.lds,espn
```

It's clear that the problem is that as I append the whole followers_list (which contains all the usernames of the people the bot followed) the names repeat. So I need a way to only append the new names. 
And I know that I can just change the code to 'w' to create a whole new file every time but that creates a problem because after I stop the bot and if I don't unfollow the users from that list and start the bot again I will lose all the names from the file, which I don't want.

So I need suggestions so that after the bot is stopped the file.txt looks like this:

```
kr.dramas_,marcelly.lds,espn,
```

Comment: Before appending, you can read the file first, store its output into a list, compare it with followers list, and append unique items instead of followers list - does that make sense?

Comment: Ok this works. But I had to create a new function and everything. So I don't think this solution is optimal but it gets the job done. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest that once you've followed everyone, you can read all of the names from the file into a list/set and then add names that aren't in the list/set into it. Then simply overwrite the old file.

```
followers_list = [] # will be populated with follower names

with open("file.txt", 'r') as file:
  file_names = file.readline().split(",")

for follower in followers_list:
  if follower not in file_names:
    file_names.append(follower)

with open("file.txt", 'w') as file:
  file.write(",".join(file_names))
```